# How to place something inside DIV with C#

Tags: c#, html

Hello everybody
How can I add something in my div (something like a banner) trough my codebehind?

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="Server">

</div>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (IsPostBack)
      return;

   ?????????

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a Banner control or text to add, you can do something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (IsPostBack)
      return;

    myDiv.InnerText = "some text";
    myDiv.Controls.Add(new Banner("someBannerArgs"));
    myDiv.Controls.AddAt(1,new Banner("someBannerArgs"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will add whatever HTML you want inside myDiv.

```
myDiv.Controls.Add(new Literal("some html"));
```

Comment: If there's any content on that div won't it desapear?

Comment: Thank you Jordan for a quick answer